# Sort WP_User_Query by meta_key value with pre_user_query

Tags: wp-user-query

I'm trying to order my users by their Member Number - which is a custom meta value. It seems I can't easily orderby a `meta_value`. I've read a few workarounds but I can't get my head around it. This is my code so far...

```
function sort_by_member_number( $vars ) {
    if ( isset( $vars->query_vars['orderby'] ) && 'member-number' == $vars->query_vars['orderby'] ) {
        $vars = array_merge(
            $vars->query_vars, array(
                'meta_key' => 'arcc_member_number'
            )
        );
    }
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'sort_by_member_number' );
```

`arcc_member_number` is a numeric value - how can I extend this to sort by that value?

Answer (score 1):

As written, this is unlikely to do anything. If you add a couple of `var_dump`s like this:

```
function sort_by_member_number( $vars ) {
  var_dump($vars);
  if ( isset( $vars->query_vars['orderby'] ) && 'member-number' == $vars->query_vars['orderby'] ) {
      $vars = array_merge(
          $vars->query_vars, array(
              'meta_key' => 'arcc_member_number'
          )
      );
  }
  var_dump($vars);
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'sort_by_member_number' );
```

You will notice that nothing has changed before and after your code, and you won't find your `arrc_member_number` value in there anywhere. And, if you look at that dumped data, you will notice that the query has already been constructed (sample query only):

```
["query_fields"]=>
  string(30) "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_users.*"
["query_from"]=>
  string(13) "FROM wp_users"
["query_where"]=>
  string(9) "WHERE 1=1"
["query_orderby"]=>
  string(28) "ORDER BY user_registered ASC"
["query_limit"]=>
  NULL
```

And if you [look in the source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.2/wp-includes/user.php#L544) for where the query actually runs, those are the properties used.

In other words, `pre_user_query` does not work like `pre_get_posts`. You will need to actually parse that `query_*` values, which can be tricky and means you need to be good with SQL. If you can write your user query to be something like this...

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( 
  array ( 
    'orderby' => 'arcc_member_number',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'arcc_member_number',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
    )
  ) 
);
```

... it will get you started but you still need to alter `query_orderby` because there are hard-coded limits to what you can order by.

```
function sort_by_member_number( $vars ) {
  if ( isset( $vars->query_vars['orderby'] ) && 'arcc_member_number' == $vars->query_vars['orderby'] ) {
    $vars->query_orderby = 'ORDER BY arcc_member_number ASC';
  }
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'pre_user_query', 'sort_by_member_number' );
```

You are only gong to get users that *have* the `arcc_member_number` meta_key with that. If you need all users, just sorted by that key you need still more query manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for your help s_ha_dum. I'll do some work and get it working and post the results up here. Other contributions still accepted though.