# How to order users alphabetically by their last name?

Tags: users, user-meta, sort, order

I use the following shortcode and function to display members of some departments:

```
add_shortcode( 'list_of_members', 'members_listing' );
/* usage: [list_of_members department = 'psychology'] */

function members_listing( $department ) {

    $members = get_users( array( 'meta_key' => 'department', 'meta_value' => $department ) ); 

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $members as $member ) {
        echo '<li>' . $member->first_name . ' ' . $member->last_name . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

I'd like to order the users alphabetically by `last_name`. How can I do this?

I was inspired by this [question/answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30302/order-users-by-custom-user-meta), but I do not understand it completely.

Comment: You get the result without ordering?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/107406/21376

Comment: @bindiya-patoliya Yes, you can see it [here](http://upsic.org/psih/catedra-de-psihologie/membri).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't use built-in functionality of PHP?

Put the following line right before the `foreach`:

```
usort($members, create_function('$a, $b', 'return strnatcasecmp($a->last_name, $b->last_name);'));
```

**References:**

- [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)
- [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php)
- [`strnatcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcasecmp.php)

Comment: I added your first line of code (before of your EDIT) to my function and I got the desired result, without to touch the rest of code, this just works. Your edited version of this function (after of your EDIT) also works, but it has two `foreach`. I don't get the fields `first_name` and `last_name` because they exists in the `$members` variable (in my code) or in the `$users` variable (in your code), from user meta data. Or not? I am not at all a coder, so maybe I do not understand. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out (that easily). I just wasn't that sure about the fields you get from `get_users`. However, I now confirmed (for myself) that you get an array of `WP_User` objects - which have the `first_name` and `last_name` field/property. I was unsure because of [this return example](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users#Returns). So, you are absolutely right to use the short version. Anyway, glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

Add orderby=>last_name,order=>DESC in your get_users argument.
Hope this will help you.

```
$members = get_users( array( 'meta_key' => 'department', 'meta_value' => $department, 'orderby' => 'last_name', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

Comment: According with [get_users documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) `order_by=>'last_name'` is not a valid value but it can works, I'd like to know if it is working.

Comment: Sorry, this can't possibly work. The [valid `orderby` values](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/user.php#L413) are hard-coded and `last_name` isn't one of them. Pass a wrong value and you default to `user_login`.

Comment: @cybnet Your code works, the order has changed, but without any sense (not alphabetical order).

Comment: See my previous comment where I talked about my doubts and the comment of @s_ha_dum who confirmed my doubt. `order_by=>'last_name'` is not valid and is replaced by the default order which is `user_login`. You will have to perform the query and reorder the users array using built-in PHP function as suggested by @tf in his answer.

Answer (score -1):

I modified your function:

```
add_shortcode( 'list_of_members', 'members_listing' );
/* usage: [list_of_members department = 'psychology'] */

function members_listing( $department ) {

   $members = get_users( array( 'meta_key' => 'department', 'meta_value' => $department, 'orderby' => 'last_name', 'order' => 'DESC' ) ); 

   echo '<ul>';
   foreach ( $members as $member ) {
      echo '<li>' . $member->first_name . ' ' . $member->last_name . '</li>';
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

Just added two more parameters two your arguments

Comment: It would be nice if this worked, but last_name isn't a valid value to pass to orderby. :(

Comment: Chris you are right. For others please do not follow my above answer.